# How to read the body content of a http get request by the outside?

Tags: javascript, scope, request

```
  var request = require("request");
  var path = "xxx.json";
  getBody : function(callback, path) {
      var self = this;
      var options = {
        method : "GET",
        uri: path,
        headers: {
          'authorization-type': 'application/json',
          'Connection':    'keep-alive',
          'Accept':        '*/*',
         },
        json: true,
      };

      request.get(options, function(error, response, body){
        self.key = body.key;  
        console.log(self.key);
      });
     console.log(self.key);
    }
```

The second console.log give always an undefined, 
How can I read the content of body when I'm out of the request.get? And I've tried with fucntion callback and also global variable, none of them works, thanks in advance for yours suggestions.

Comment: you can use a global variable and then assign into it inside the request.get method. Then you can call that global from the outside. This is to do with the scope of a variable

Comment: @KevinRED — That is, more or less, what they are trying to do. It isn't wokring because they are trying to read the value before they set it. Using a global variable won't change the order of events.

Comment: @Quentin, forgot that, thanks